# Ajax - Check database table value every second

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to check a value of a field in a database table every second and print it out in a html div. For some reason this is not working. The Inspector(F12) does not throw any error messages. Here is my code. If anyone can point me in the right direction it is highly appreciated:

php code:

```
echo("<input type='hidden' id='hidSessionOwner' value='".$userid."'/>");
```

Ajax code:

```
function check_invited_users(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/checkinvitedusers.php',
        data: {
            id: $('#hidSessionOwner').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(console) console.log('Status = ' + response.status);
            if(response.status > 0){
            $('#divInvited').html(response);

            }
        }
    });
}
var check_search_status_interval;
$(document).ready(function(){
    check_search_status_interval  = setInterval(function() {
            check_invited_users();
    }, 1000);
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="divInvited"></div>
```

and here is the code in the checkinvitedusers.php file:

```
$user_id = ($_POST['id']);

// Build SQL
$invite_search_sql = "select count from class_user_invites where user_id=".$user_id;
$result = mysql_query($invite_search_sql, $con) or die ("Error in query: $invite_search_sql " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$response['status'] = $row[0];

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Is your ajax call working? Check in console or add alert() in check_invited_users()

Comment: Put an Error handling block in your ajax. then you can see where the control is.

Comment: reason could be url with ' /  ' before pagename , json_encode(array('status' =>$response)) or round brackets ( $_POST['id'] )

Comment: also $('#divInvited').html(response); with $('#divInvited').html(response.status);

Comment: Change `$user_id = ($_POST['id']);` to `$user_id = $_GET['id'];` and run `checkinvitedusers.php?id=xx` to see if the PHP is outputting any values correctly.

Comment: Check the quests and responses on the network tab of the F12 dev tools. Are the requests done? Are the responses correct? This way you can debug if the problem is in the client side code or the server side code

Comment: All, I have tested all of your suggestions. The error handling block does not return any errors, the php returns the expected value when doing the test suggested by Oli and the changes suggested by Luca does not make any changes. Also the F12 suggestion does not give any results. Maybe I'm not reading it correctly...?

Answer (score 1):

Needed async: false option in the Ajax function.

Comment: Appreciate if you could be a bit more specific about what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

USE ASYNC FLASE OPTION AND TRY UP. i think you can solve this problem.
                                                                    `function check_invited_users(){
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/checkinvitedusers.php',
        data: $("#hidSessionOwner").serialize(),
           async: false`

just try this and see.i think it is a solution for your question.

Comment: tested this but no love. The thing is that I cannot see the script in the inspector (F12 > Network) in FF either. I thought it would be there.